# Laplace's equation and parallel plate capacitors

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, capacitance

This might be a dumb question, but I've been trying to figure it out for a while now. If you got two plate capacitors placed in parallel in a grounded box, one with a potential of -1, and one with potential +1, how can i solve the Laplace equation inside the box?

Many thanks for any help, and if needed, I can send some additional information.

[image]

This is a picture of the box, and I've so far gotten this:

[image]

Not sure how to correct it

Comment: Perhaps a drawing will help understand the situation. At the moment the geometry is unclear,

Comment: You can solve it numerically applying dirichlet boundary conditions.

Comment: This can't be a university assignment because there is no simple solution for this problem (other than numerical as mentioned by gsomani). The two dimensional problem (infinitely long plates in an infinite tube) can be solved with analytic functions if I remember correctly.

Comment: @FlatterMann, yeah its suppposed to be solved numerically, but I'm unable to figure out how

Comment: Solving Laplace equation for a capacitor with finite size plates is difficult (and I am not even sure it can be solved analytically.) So it is worth clarifying what exactly you are looking for: a numerical solution? A solution for idealized case where the plates are very big? Something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electric field for point charge in a smoothly-varying dielectric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/538058/electric-field-for-point-charge-in-a-smoothly-varying-dielectric)

Comment: @RogerVadim I'm looking for a numerical solution, to fiugre out the potential inside the box

Comment: You get an electromagnetic field solver to do that for you. If you want to know how they work, then you have to read the literature on numerical methods. Physicists are not particularly interested in numerical methods unless they need them for a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Attached are the resultant figures from my numerical calculations using the finite element method.
The figure is a contour plot of the electric potential. The potential contours between the +1.0V and -1.0V electrodes are parallel.
This is how it should be.
[image]

As others have written, it is difficult to find an analytic solution to this problem.
Even if it could be found, it would be an infinite series, and coding the software to calculate it may be more difficult than coding the finite element method software.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but how did you program it to get those oval shapes? I'm pretty new to programming and can't get it to oval instead of circles as in my image

Comment: If we look at the potential along the line of the high potential side electrode in your diagram, both sides are bright yellow and the center is much darker yellow. This means that the result is a change in potential along the electrode. Since the potential at the electrodes is solved as a constant condition, your result is inconsistent. If you use a well known numerical solution method such as FEM (finite element method) or FDM (finite difference method), you will get the result that the potential at the electrode is constant. You will then get an oval shape result.

Comment: Okay, but I'm unable to figure out how to do that, I've looked around but struggle to figure out how.

Comment: One option is to ask your organisation if you can use commercial code or not.

Or, to develop your own code.
I googled around and found the finite difference code on [this site](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1087025/Using-Python-to-Solve-Computational-Physics-Proble).
Starting with this code and modifying it to meet the internal constraints would help solve the problem.

There is a free FE code  [FEAPpv](http://projects.ce.berkeley.edu/feap/feappv/). This FE code can be used to solve static temperature distributions. However, using FEAPpv is not easy and requires some effort.